# access to private attribute in abstract class dart

Tags: dart

I need access to private attribute in abstract class inside flutter SDK. I reduce my problem to this case:

```
abstract class Person{
  final String _name = "Testing...";
}

class Employee extends Person{
  String get name =>_name;
}

main(){
  var emp = new Employee();
  print(emp.name);
}
```

If I put the Person class and the Employee class in the same .dart file, I can access the private attribute _name in Person from Employee, but I can't do the same if I move Person class to another .dart file.

dart documentation says: If an identifier starts with an underscore _ , it's private to its library. Libraries not only provide APIs, but are a unit of privacy: identifiers that start with an underscore _ are visible only inside the library.

How can I make them belong to the same library when they are in different files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not well documented, but if you have two `.dart` files that are meant to be part of the same library, you can use `library`, `part`, and `part of`.  You'd have one `.dart` file be the entry point to your library:

`foo.dart`:

```dart
library library_name;
part 'bar.dart';
```

`bar.dart`:

```dart
part of library_name;
...
```

and then consumers import the whole library via `import 'foo.dart';`.

The Flutter SDK makes use of it, and you can refer to its source code for examples.

Comment: that works :) thx

Answer (score 0):

I think the _name member in Person class should be protected and named without _. I think this kind of implementation is wrong because both of them should be packed in the same library/file. so you can change the structure of your class ! sry if it is not your answer :(