# Is there any way to define protected properties or methods in dart language mixin?

Tags: dart

I want to create one dart `mixin` and use it in other classes and access some properties only in those classes but to be private to the other clients.

I will provide a very minimalistic code to make my point and describe the issue

```
mixin MyMixin {
  int _privateExample = 1;
  int howToMakeThisProtected = 22;
}

class UseMixin with MyMixin {
  void tryMe() {
     print(this._privateExample); // error as it is private to the mixin
     print(this.howToMakeThisProtected); // prints 22 but also is public which I don't want
  }
}


Future<void> main() async {
  final um = UseMixin();
  um.tryMe();

  // this is ugly and I want to hide howToMakeThisProtected from the world but only to be visible to mixin<->parent, so protected visibility
  print('outside class ${um.howToMakeThisProtected}'); 
}
```

I am using dart with Flutter if that matters.

Comment: The answer is always going to be "no", because the language simply doesn't support anything except private or public members. This is worth a read though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350655/how-do-i-emulate-protected-methods-in-dart

Comment: @Clive thanks for the reply. Someone messages me and pointed to `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';` and @protected annotation. I have to try that not sure if it gets the job done and is officially as a solution or not related...

Comment: It's not perfect, and it only raises a warning rather than an error by default, but I think it's probably the most elegant way available. I'm not sure you could ever consider it an "official" solution, as officially Dart doesn't support the concept

Comment: Also be aware that `_privateExample` is not private to the `mixin`.  It is private to the Dart *library* (which usually means the `.dart` file, but [you can specify that multiple files should be part of the same "library"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808002/)).

Answer (score 0):

[`package:meta`](https://pub.dev/packages/meta) adds a [`protected` annotation](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/protected-constant.html) that the analyzer recognizes and warns about.

> Used to annotate an instance member in a class or mixin which is meant to be visible only within the declaring library, and to other instance members of the class or mixin, and their subtypes.

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

mixin MyMixin {
  int _privateExample = 1;

  @protected
  int howToMakeThisProtected = 22;
}
```

The warning can be [increased](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#customizing-analysis-rules) to an error severity level if need be.

`analysis_options.yaml`

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    invalid_use_of_protected_member: error
```